# Scala: copy object of a derived case class

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a case class and I extend it as so

```
case class A(num: Int)

case class B(firstNum: Int, otherNum: Int) extends A(firstNum)
```

When I want to copy an object of type `B`, the signature of `copy` only accepts parameters of case class `A`.

```
B(1, 2).copy(num = 2) // compiles

B(1, 2).copy(firstNum = 2) // doesn't compile
```

Why does it do that, and how do I copy (/update) objects of type `B`?

Comment: Which ancient Scala version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [thats how `copy` works with case class inheritance](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/3289), by design, and is another general reason why you shouldn't do case class inheritance (the primary reason is the possbility of breaking equality).

Instead, make `A` a regular class. Note that if you implement `copy` for `A`, one won't be automatically generated for `B`.